# How do I get the feature id after featureAdded signal (PyQGIS)?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I'm trying to make an edit form in QGIS (Python code) ,and i want after feature drawing to get the id, and the feature to be selected.
Do you have any ideas to do that?

Tried so far:

```
self.iface.activeLayer().featureAdded.connect(self.myfonction)

def myfonction(self): 
    for feat in self.iface.activeLayer().getFeatures():
        self.iface.activeLayer().setSelectedFeatures([feat.id()])
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have so far?

Comment: self.iface.activeLayer().featureAdded.connect(self.myfonction)
    def myfonction(self):
                for feat in self.iface.activeLayer().getFeatures():
            self.iface.activeLayer().setSelectedFeatures([feat.id()])

Comment: I added your code into your question, for readability purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the doc](http://www.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#ac914dd316a4bb50eb432515950583806), it seems that `featureAdded` sends the feature id as argument. You can replace `def myfonction(self)` with `def myfonction(self, fId)` and use `fId` in your function.