# Get id of last added feature in qgis python action

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, actions

I created a python qgis action that open the dialog form so the user can add a new feature.

```
maintenance_lyr = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayer('od_maintenance_event20180212171049766')

maintenance_lyr.startEditing()
qgis.utils.iface.setActiveLayer(maintenance_lyr)
qgis.utils.iface.actionAddFeature().trigger()
```

My question: How can I get the id of the newly created feature?

Comment: Perhaps this post might help: [How do I get the feature id after featureAdded signal (PyQGIS)?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/181131/how-do-i-get-the-feature-id-after-featureadded-signal-pyqgis)

Comment: I tried that already, but 'self' doesn't seems to be defined in python code for actions. I'm wrong?

Comment: `self` is used for plugins, you can ignore these whenever they are mentioned.

Comment: Ok I will try, thank you. Should I replace 'self' by qgis.utils. ?

Comment: Yes or you could set `from qgis.utils import iface` at the beginning and then use `iface` instead of `qgis.utils.iface`.

Comment: Great! Will mark this post as a duplicate of the other :)